# Regex Expression for English letters, no special characters or numbers, 32 or greater

Tags: java, regex, string

This is my first time implementing regex in Java or any language. I am trying to create two different regex expressions. The first regex expression needs to ensure that:

1. The string is 32 or greater characters
2. The string only contains English letters
3. The string does not contain numbers
4. The string does not contain any special characters (!, @, #, $, %, ^, &, *, (, ), -, _, +, =, ., , , >, <, ?, `, ~, /, |, \, {, }, [, ])
5. The string does not contain any spaces or tabs

The second regex expression needs to ensure that:

1. The string is contains the letter: L or the letter R.
2. L or R must be uppercase

If someone could explain the process for both that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is plenty of information about regular expressions all over the internet. For example, Oracle provides this [Regular Expression Lesson](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). If you really want to understand how they work and how to write them you should go through tutorials like the one linked above.

Comment: Programming is about clarity. Points 3, 4 and 5 are redundant and irrelevant due to point 2. `[a-zA-Z]{32,}`, `.*L.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah okay, I'll do my best to answer your question and explain thoroughly while not assuming or guessing!

This answer builds off of what Dallas S replied with (or at least shares some similarity).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = "ThisIsATestStringThatIsBeingUsedInThisExample";
        System.out.println("Test String Length: " + s.length());
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]{32,}$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        System.out.println("Found = " + (m.find() ? "True" : "Flase"));
        if (m.find()) {
            String str = s.substring(m.start(), m.end());
            System.out.println("Result = " + str);
        }
    }
}
```

Explaining the regex more and how it relates to your first part of your question:
Given your requirements of,

> The string only contains English letters

and

> The string does not contain numbers

and

> The string does not contain any special characters (!, @, #, $, %, ^, &, *, (, ), -, _, +, =, ., , , >, <, ?, `, ~, /, |, \, {, }, [, ])

and

> The string does not contain any spaces or tabs

This was grouped into the portion of the regex that contains the *'[A-Za-z]'* code. Meaning a character class of any upper or lower case alphabet characters can be accepted for this regex.

Then, for the part your specify of:

> The string is 32 or greater characters

This is accomplished with the portion of code that is *'{32,}'* This tells to find a match that requires 32 or more (thus no following number after comma) characters.

Note, the *'^'* symbol in the regex anchors the start of matching at beginning of string. Also, the *'$'* anchors the end of matching at the end of the string.

As for part 2 of your question, I would simply avoid a regex and use as Dallas S suggested, a contains() call to look for the 'L' or 'R' characters.

Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more documentation of the java Pattern class.
Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for more documentation of the java Matcher class.

(Please accept this as an answer if it works/helps and community please don't take away my response powers! I read feedback to answer, not suggest!)

Cheers

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression: `/[a-z]{32,}/i` for your first question. This sets an ignoreCase flag, allows for characters in the range a-z and allows for 32 or more. Using java the way to use it would look like:

`myString.matches("(?i)[a-z]{32,}")`

For the second you could just use the .contains method.

`myString.contains("L") || myString.contains("R")`

Both of these expressions would return a boolean.